# I have an error with my automatic cookieclicker code, as seen below, does anyone know how to fix this? I tried different things but nothing worked yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

I have a code that automates cookieclicker, however I keep getting an error, the code is:

```py
def cookieclicker():
    global driver
    COOKIE = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bigCookie")
    for i in range(500000000):
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
            COOKIE.click()

        products = [driver.find_element(By.ID, "productPrice" + str(i)) for i in range(0, 18, 1)]

        for item in products:
            cookie_count = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookies")
            count = int(cookie_count.text.split(" ")[0].replace(',', ''))
            value = int(item.text.replace(',', ''))
            if count >= value:
                action = ActionChains(driver)
                action.click(item)
                action.perform()

cookieclicker()
```

The error I get is:

```
    value = int(item.text.replace(',', ''))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the content of `item.text` when the error happens?

Comment: it checks the item in the products list and that lists contains 18 different prices, **15**, **100**, **1,100**, **12,000**. I added the replace method to replace teh ',' with nothing, but it seems like it still does not recognize the content as an integer

Comment: You are clearly expecting that `item.text` contains a number with commas in it, like `1,234`. But for one of the elements of `products`, `.text` is the empty string (or contains nothing but commas). One way to fix this would be to test it for the data you expect before calling `int()` on it. But it might be a symptom of a deeper problem, such as, the call to `find_element()` doesn’t do what you think it does.

Comment: the list containt of 17 different numbers and from the second to last place in the list the numbers contain a comma. however these numbers dont appear at the start of the game but they appear when you buy more and more upgrades. how can I code it so it only checks when they are appearing on the screen

Comment: it seems you get empty string - so simply first use `replace()` and later use `if/else` to run `int()` when string is not  empty. ie. `if item.text: ... `. OR put code in `try/except` to catch error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get empty string - so you could use `if/else` to check it before `int()`

```
value = item.text.replace(',', '')
if value:
    value = int(value)
    if count >= value:
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.click(item)
        action.perform()
```

Or you could use `try/except` to catch error

```
try:
    value = int(item.text.replace(',', ''))
    if count >= value:
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.click(item)
        action.perform()
except ValueError as ex:
    print("Exception:", ex)
```

Comment: That works! only thing now is that it clicks the cookie way slower than before.

Comment: now at least it works. But if it works slower then you have different problem and you should create new question on new page. But first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and  it helps to see what code is doing. And maybe this way you will see which part make it slow. Maybe you search wrong elements and later it has to skip them - and this needs time.